# Java library for MongoDB-like JSON processing

Tags: java, json, mongodb

We have a use-case of processing JSON documents in a Java application. Although we do not use MongoDB, I would like to know if there are any Java library for JSON processing that supports similar MongoDB functionalities like querying, filtering, mapping, aggregating, unwind, etc.

Comment: I think you should have used this  http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/

Answer (score 0):

You can map your json string to java object and query the object itself. There are many library that can achieve this. You can use [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/) for querying object property using PropertyUtils class and [Google-Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for mapping your json string to java object. Refer below's code.

```
String json = "{status : true, statusMsg : 'Success', preferredSchedule : {dateStr : '20 Apr 2015'}}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
VpVO vpVO = gson.fromJson(json, VpVO.class);
try {
    Object dateObj = PropertyUtils.getProperty(vpVO, "preferredSchedule.dateStr");
    System.out.println(dateObj); // result will print 20 Apr 2015
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for some high-level functionalities similar to MongoDB's.